# convert json data to angular object in angular2

Tags: c#, angular, json.net

Webmethod code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static string getBatch(string program,string location, string createdby)
 {
    List<batTerSec> Masterobj = new List<batTerSec>();        
                    batTerSec temp = new batTerSec();
                    temp.batch = tmobj;
                    temp.term = tmobj1;
                    temp.section = tmobj2;
                    Masterobj.Add(temp);       
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Masterobj);
}
public class batTerSec
{
    public string batch { get; set; }
    public string term { get; set; }
    public string section { get; set; }    }
```

json data

```
  { "d": "[{\"batch\":\"5\",\"term\":\"TERM V\",\"section\":\"Section I\"},{\"batch\":\"5\",\"term\":\"TERM VI\",\"section\":\"Section I\"},{\"batch\":\"5\",\"term\":\"TERM VII\",\"section\":\"Section I\"},{\"batch\":\"6\",\"term\":\"TERM I\",\"section\":\"Section I\"},{\"batch\":\"6\",\"term\":\"TERM II\",\"section\":\"Section I\"}]" }
```

Required like  following

```
 [
    { 'batch': '28', 'term': 'Term I', 'section': 'Section I' },
    { 'batch': '28', 'term': 'Term I', 'section': 'Section II' }      
]
```

how to convert Newtonsoft json to angular2 object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a JSON-encoded string in you JSON so you just need to parse it twice:

```
let final= JSON.parse(data.d);
```

You just need to use the `final` value to get the content of your JSON.

**However**, it is weird that you are receiving data encoded like this, maybe you could tweak the server to get properly-encoded JSON object and not a string.

Comment: I put c# class also check it means i should pass Masterobj  directly instead of convert

Comment: I got this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: then just `JSON.parse(data.d)`

Comment: same error getting normal angularjs this function works but in angular2 showed  error

Comment: then provide the code where you are calling this because I have no idea of the context. if I run this in my dev console, it works...

Comment: That's because data is `undefined`, just put the real variable name